# Not until ( sentence ) + do (sentence)

Tags: grammar

Can someone explain the structure of the following sentence?

- *It was not until hours later did I find him*.

Does it have anything to do with emphasis ?

Answer (score 4):

The sentence is not grammatical. It should either be

> It was not until hours later *that* I *found* him.

or

> Not until hours later did I find him.

This structure indeed emphasizes the temporal adverb.
It means the same thing as

> I didn't find him until hours later. (= I found him hours later)

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a conflation of that first sentence and a more complex construction with the same meaning, _Not until hours later did I find him_. Either one is correct, but they don't have the same structure, so they can't be combined at will.

Comment: I would disagree on those two sentences having the same meaning. "until hours later" implies a relatively long period, whereas "only hours later" invokes a relatively short period.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I edited my answer accordingly.